# Twitterizer bug on FriendsIds function?

Tags: c#, twitterizer, .net

I'm trying to retrieve a list of all Twitter friends using the following function:

TwitterResponse tr = TwitterFriendship.FriendsIds(tokens);
for (int i = 0; i < tr.ResponseObject.Count; i++) { alFriends.Add(tr.ResponseObject[i]); }

and I get the following error on the first line:

**Invalid Cast Exception: "Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'."**

To get followers I use the following (which is the same as the code for FriendsIds), which works perfectly fine - without any "Unable to cast..." error:

TwitterResponse tr1 = TwitterFriendship.FollowersIds(tokens);
for (int j = 0; j < tr1.ResponseObject.Count; j++) { alFollowers.Add(tr1.ResponseObject[j]); }

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?
Or, is there another way to retrieve all friends (using TwitterFriendship.Friends(tokens) only gets me the first 100 friends - I need the entire friends list)

Thanks.

Robert

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue has been addressed, but is awaiting the next official release. You should get the latest source code (available on the [downloads](http://www.twitterizer.net/downloads/) page).

Comment: Thanks. I checked the download page, but I'm already using the latest version: 2.3.3   Do you know when version 2.3.4 will come out?

Comment: I don't mean the latest released binary. There is a link closer to the top of the page to get the latest source code from our repository.

The next release will be 2.4. Unfortunately, we're volunteers, so putting a time frame on task completion is difficult. You can see our progress, however, here: http://pm.twitterizer.net/projects/twitterizer/roadmap

Comment: Thanks for your help. I downloaded the latest source code and this solves the problem with the FriendsIds function. However, it seems this latest version introduced a new bug. The following function throws an exception: TwitterResponse<TwitterSearchResultCollection> result = TwitterSearch.Search(kw, so) with the following error: Error converting value 0.179 to type 'Twitterizer.TwitterSearchResultCollection'

Comment: Hmm. That should have already been addressed, too. The code must have gotten rolled back somehow. I'll look into it as soon as I can.